# mvn command not found when ran in init.d service

Tags: linux, bash, maven

I'm facing an issue with creating `init.d` service. Following is my run.sh file which executes completely fine (As root user)

```
mvn install -DskipTests
mvn exec:java
```

But when I execute same file as service in init.d (service run start). I get

> > mvn command not found

Following is my start method

```
start() {
    if [ -f /var/run/$PIDNAME ] && kill -0 $(cat /var/run/$PIDNAME); then
    echo 'Service already running' >&2
    return 1
    fi
    echo 'Starting service…' >&2
    CMD="$SCRIPT &> \"$LOGFILE\" & echo \$!"
    su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS > "$PIDFILE"
    echo 'Service started' >&2
}
```

Link to complete script which i'm using

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/naholyr/4275302/raw/9df4ef3f4f2c294c9585f11d1c8593b62bdd52d3/service.sh

RUN AS value is set as `root`

Comment: What is your she-bang line at top of script? `#!/bin/sh` or any other?

Comment: it is #!/bin/bash

Comment: Can you add a line  `echo $PATH` just before calling `maven` while running from `init.d`? and see its contents? and compare the `$PATH`  value while just running successfully in command line

Comment: when i run it on command line. I get **/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/integration/maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin** but in service i get **/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin**

Comment: I'm login as root user. Why it is different ?

Comment: Ahh! there is the problem

Comment: Whats your solution to it. Should i update $PATH in service or do you suggest any other thing. And can you also explain why they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command using `sudo` you are effectively running it as the superuser or `root`.

The reason that the `root` user is not finding your command is likely that the `PATH` environment variable for `root` does not include the directory where `maven` is located (quite evident as in the comments). Hence the reason for command not found error.

Add `PATH` to your script and that it includes `/opt/inte‌​gration/maven/apache‌​-maven-3.3.9/bin`. Since the `init` script won't share the `PATH` environment variable with the rest of the system (since it being run much ahead of the actual updates of `$PATH` in the `.bash_profile`) you need to set it directly on your script and make sure maven is in there, for example, add the below line to the `init` script in the beginning.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin‌​:/root/bin:/opt/inte‌​gration/maven/apache‌​-maven-3.3.9/bin
```

Comment: but thing is i'm not running any command with sudo. Does **service <name> start** run with sudo by default ?

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood: But you mentioned `RUN AS value is set as root`? What does that mean?